# Issue with shouldEnableEffects

Tags: sprite-kit, skscene, skeffectnode

When I start a new project in Xcode 6 iOS 8.1 and use this line of code

```
    self.shouldEnableEffects = YES;
```

this happens https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GPUkEAnHW7s

It wouldn't be a problem if I had control over it, but no matter what I try (changing blending mode or adding CIFilters to the scene) the result is always that.

I've searched around the web and have tried to duplicate examples that i've seen and it comes out to the posted video basically.

Comment: Post your attempts (code) because if this is all you do, the "effect" may be expected. Blending mode alone will probably not do much, and the CIFilter must be one of the compatible ones with the correct parameters. See SKEffectNode reference (also has an example): https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKEffectNode_Ref/index.html

Comment: Let me put together another sample and I'll update the question.

Comment: Oh I should also add that I tried to use the "CIColorPosterize" filter. (Nothing changed)